# Transcendental Equation: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, floating-point, integer, sympy

I am trying to solve the following in SymPy, but I am getting the 'can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'' error:

```
F = Symbol('F')
S=7*10**9
L=500*10**(-9)
k=10.37*10**(-9)
e=1*10**(-9),48*10**(-9),1
c=25*10**(-9)
solve(F-((S*A)/(1+(e*c/k**2)*sec((2*L/k)*(sqrt(F*A/E))))))


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/<ipython-input-51-3831e4f1c049> in <module>()
----> 1 solve(float(F-((S*A)/(1+(e*c/k**2)*sec((2*L/k)*(sqrt(F*A/E)))))))

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Answer (score 1):

`e` is a tuple, because of the commas.

```
>>> e=1*10**(-9),48*10**(-9),1
>>> e
(1e-09, 4.8000000000000006e-08, 1)
```

You can multiply sequences like tuples only with integers, not floats, which is what gives the error.

```
>>> e*2
(1e-09, 4.8000000000000006e-08, 1, 1e-09, 4.8000000000000006e-08, 1)
>>> e*2.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

I think you didn't mean to create a tuple in the middle of an equation, so you should fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to solve that for F will fail even if you fix the problem with e because it is a non-linear equation that SymPy cannot solve. You will have better success with nsolve, however.

Comment: In [138]: nsolve(F-((S*A)/(1+(e*c/k**2)*sec((2*L/k)*(sqrt(F*A/E))))))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/<ipython-input-138-a0f0bffb2790> in <module>()
----> 1 nsolve(F-((S*A)/(1+(e*c/k**2)*sec((2*L/k)*(sqrt(F*A/E))))))

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Answer (score 0):

```
from sympy.mpmath import *
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy import *
from sympy.solvers import solve  
F = Symbol('F')
S=7*10**9  
A = 19622.5*10**(-18)
L=500*10**(-9)
k=10.37*10**(-9)
E=8.69*10**9
e=1*10**(-9),48*10**(-9),1
c=25*10**(-9) 
solve(F-((S*A)/(1+(e*c/k**2)*sec((2*L/k)*(sqrt(F*A/E))))))
```

Output:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/ in ()
----> 1 solve(F-((S*A)/(1+(e*c/k**2)*sec((2*L/k)*(sqrt(F*A/E))))))

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mpmath/ctx_mp_python.pyc in f(x, **kwargs)
    982         def f(x, **kwargs):
    983             if type(x) not in ctx.types:
--> 984                 x = ctx.convert(x)
    985             prec, rounding = ctx._prec_rounding
    986             if kwargs:

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mpmath/ctx_mp_python.pyc in convert(ctx, x, strings)
    660         if hasattr(x, '*mpmath*'):
    661             return ctx.convert(x.*mpmath*(prec, rounding))
--> 662         return ctx._convert_fallback(x, strings)
    663 
    664     def isnan(ctx, x):

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mpmath/ctx_mp.pyc in _convert_fallback(ctx, x, strings)
    559             else:
    560                 raise ValueError("can only create mpf from zero-width interval")
--> 561         raise TypeError("cannot create mpf from " + repr(x))
    562 
    563     def mpmathify(ctx, *args, **kwargs):

TypeError: cannot create mpf from 2.25805523590334e-24*F

where as, if I use, nsolve:
    nsolve(F-((S*A)/(1+(e*c/k**2)*sec((2*L/k)*(sqrt(F*A/E))))))

### Output:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/ in ()
----> 1 nsolve(F-((S*A)/(1+(e*c/k**2)*sec((2*L/k)*(sqrt(F*A/E))))))

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'